# While changing the orientation list item are repeating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

When I change the orientation of my application, the list item in the application are repeating and many of the items are not visible in landscape mode.

source code: https://github.com/amar0891/Aroma-Holiday.git

As I have less reputation, I am sorry for not posting the image of expected output.

Resultant output

[image]

Comment: Do you need landscape mode? You could just prevent it from being displayed in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that you are getting unexpected results is that you are performing view modifications inside of the if(convertView == null) block. If you pull the code out as follows, I think it will fix the issue for you:

```
if(convertView == null) {
    convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_adapter_view, null);
}

final TextView itemDetailsViews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_details);
final TextView itemsDescriptionsViews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);
final ImageView itemImagesViews = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
itemDetailsView.setText(itemDetails[position]);
itemsDescriptionsView.setText(itemDescriptions[position]);
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        itemImagesViews.setImageResource(R.drawable.plane);
        break;
    case 1:
        itemImagesViews.setImageResource(R.drawable.train);
        break;
    case 2:
        itemImagesViews.setImageResource(R.drawable.bus);
        break;
    case 3:
        itemImagesViews.setImageResource(R.drawable.hotel);
        break;
    case 4:
        itemImagesViews.setImageResource(R.drawable.holiday);
        break;
    case 5:
        itemImagesViews.setImageResource(R.drawable.booking);
        break;
    case 6:
        itemImagesViews.setImageResource(R.drawable.discount);
        break;
    default:
        itemImagesViews.setImageResource(R.drawable.train);
        break;
}
```

Comment: I see you used the code I left above, did that fix your issue? If so, could you accept the answer please?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are not ready for displaying items in landscape mode. In that case, you can simply do this in **AndroidManifest**.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

The main attribute here is **screenOrientation**. This declares your view to be in a certain mode. Related Google webpage @ [activity-element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen), search for screenOrientation.

However, previous answers related to getView() would be the better solution. Meantime you can use this attribute until you're more ready to handle your issues with the landscape orientation.